# Do all assemblies in my project need to be recompiled and re-deployed if a class changes?

Tags: c#, .net

If I have a class library with a certain number of public classes (5 for this example) and I have 3 projects that depend on this library (for this example) and I decide to change one of the classes, but only 1 of the 3 projects depend on that class.

Do I need to compile/link/deploy all 3 projects?

Basically does .NET depend on the names of the classes or does it have some type of addressing dependency? (I have a c++ background, so I know in c++ I would have to redeploy all 3 projects).

Comment: Why would you need to recompile/link/deploy to all projects in C++ anyway if only 1 project would be using this new class?

Comment: this is why you should embrace Open/Close principle.

Answer (score 3):

If the class inherits from an interface, and you do not change the interface (but only the class implementation), then you don't have to change the dependent assemblies if they rely solely on the interface for communication with the class.

If you change a class's API (like a method signature or name) on which a dependent assembly relies, then you have to fix the dependent assembly to use the new API.  This includes changes to the name of the class itself.

So the key here is to provide a stable API.  If you change the API, then you have to change the code that depends on the API.  If an assembly is not dependent (i.e. it doesn't rely on any API dependencies that you are changing), then you don't have to re-deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

If you recompile the class library project, creating a new DLL, you do not have to recompile the projects that do not depend on the changes to the DLL as long as:

- the public interface that each project depends on does not change in a breaking manner.
- The projects are still compatible with the new version number of the DLL.

If your dependent projects do not require a specific version number or version range of the DLL, the version consideration does not apply.